# Invalid column name on Insert Into statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to insert values from one table to another. However, when I run my command, I get this response.

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Invalid column name 'table1column'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Invalid column name 'othertable1column'.

Here is my code:

```
insert into table2 (column2)
   select column1
   from table1
   where table2column = table1column
   and othertable2column = othertable1column
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `table1` has field `table1column` and `othertable1column`?

Comment: I don't understand your `where` condition. Seems something wrong there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you really want an update:

```
update table2
    set column2 = column1
    from table2 join
         table1
         on table2.table1column = table1.table1column and
            table2.andothertable2column = table1;othertable1column;
```

`insert` inserts new rows.  `update` updates values in existing rows.  If you are trying to join the two tables together, then presumably the row you want is already in `table2`.